Mac Calendar.app freezes on trying to edit events
On the latest Sequoia (15.2), M1 Macbook Pro. Started happening yesterday. Any attempt to edit the body of an event causes a 1-2 minute freeze of the Calendar app, rendering it completely non-reactive/unusable in the moment when I place the cursor in any of the event fields. During the freeze, 1 CPU core seems to run at 100%.
Happens both on iCloud and on Exchange calendars.
On another M1 Mac, configured with the same accounts and same MacOS version, no such problem.
I tried

force-quitting and restarting the calendar (also with Shift)
restarting the whole Mac
disabling/re-enabling the respective calendars on the iCloud and Exchange internet accounts.

Any idea how to debug this problem? The Calendar is a life-critical app for me...
EDIT: At the suggestion of the kind commenter Linc Davis I'm posting the console error/warning log of what happens when I start the Calendar and attempt to edit (filtered to only events with "calendar" in the text)

error 11:23:09.681032+0100    Calendar    ERROR: The given date could not be rounded to midnight. This date & time may not exist in the active calendar.
Initial Start Date =  in ;
Revised Start Date =  in ;
Calendar/Locale = gregorian/;
error   11:23:09.741482+0100    calaccessd  Found 1 notifications of type SuggestionResourceChange
error   11:23:09.749680+0100    Calendar    -[AFPreferences _languageCodeWithFallback:] No language code saved, but Assistant is enabled - returning: 
error   11:23:09.750109+0100    Calendar    -[AFPreferences _languageCodeWithFallback:] No language code saved, but Assistant is enabled - returning: 
error   11:23:09.827917+0100    Calendar    Potential infinite loop, page size is zero!
fault   11:23:09.847518+0100    Calendar    Invalid view geometry: value is less than -35184372088832.
fault   11:23:09.847544+0100    Calendar    Invalid view geometry: value is less than -35184372088832.
error   11:23:09.985342+0100    tccd    TCCDProcess: identifier=com.apple.iCal, pid=51860, auid=503, euid=503, binary_path=/System/Applications/Calendar.app/Contents/MacOS/Calendar attempted to call TCCAccessRequest for kTCCServiceAccessibility without the recommended com.apple.private.tcc.manager.check-by-audit-token entitlement
fault   11:23:10.013009+0100    Calendar    Invalid view geometry: value is less than -35184372088832.
fault   11:23:10.013040+0100    Calendar    Invalid view geometry: value is less than -35184372088832.
error   11:23:10.817086+0100    tccd    TCCDProcess: identifier=com.apple.iCal, pid=51860, auid=503, euid=503, binary_path=/System/Applications/Calendar.app/Contents/MacOS/Calendar attempted to call TCCAccessRequest for kTCCServiceAccessibility without the recommended com.apple.private.tcc.manager.check-by-audit-token entitlement
error   11:23:11.808557+0100    Calendar    -[EKEventStore _deleteDraft:]: Failed to remove file from path  with error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 UserInfo={NSUserStringVariant=, NSFilePath=, NSURL=, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000023e6af0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
error   11:23:11.843420+0100    FaceTimeExtension   Bootstrapping; external subsystem UIKit_PKSubsystem refused setup
error   11:23:12.119119+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.119163+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up historical weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.119507+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.119544+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up historical weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.119821+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.119858+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up historical weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.120126+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.120444+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.120479+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.123450+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.123627+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.124933+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.124969+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.125195+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.125231+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.125349+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.125665+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.125703+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.125813+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.125973+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.126220+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.126250+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.126362+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.126571+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.126609+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.126724+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.127348+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.127392+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.127513+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.127860+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.127901+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.128042+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.128793+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.128827+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.128971+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.129180+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.129210+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.129333+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.129543+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.129580+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.129700+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.129909+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.129944+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.130058+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.130259+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.130295+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.130414+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.130640+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.130678+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.130791+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.131241+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.131366+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.131519+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.132769+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.132812+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.132967+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.133215+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.133254+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.133368+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.133461+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.133634+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.133670+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.133784+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.133980+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.134011+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.134313+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.134350+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.134463+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.134833+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.134871+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.135488+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.135525+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.137033+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.144633+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.144742+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.145035+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.145073+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.145371+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.145428+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.145646+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.145689+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.145893+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.145936+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.146161+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.146198+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.146423+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.146460+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.146676+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.146713+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.146925+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.146961+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.147229+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.147268+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.147492+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.147530+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.147860+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.148031+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.148330+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.149230+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.149360+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.149590+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.149633+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.149931+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.149970+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.150074+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.150429+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.150533+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.150712+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.151038+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.151077+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.151184+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.151520+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.151550+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.151670+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.151859+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.152168+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.152208+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.152323+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.152517+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.152553+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.152777+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location coordinate (0,0) when looking up weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.152815+0100    com.apple.CalendarWeatherKitService We received an empty location when looking up almanac weather so we will return nil results.
error   11:23:12.289130+0100    com.apple.quicklook.ThumbnailsAgent Private sandbox for com.apple.quicklook.thumbnail.CalendarExtension : quicklook-thumbnail-secure
error   11:23:12.747180+0100    Calendar    ViewBridge to RemoteViewService Terminated: Error Domain=com.apple.ViewBridge Code=18 UserInfo={com.apple.ViewBridge.error.hint=this process disconnected remote view controller -- benign unless unexpected, com.apple.ViewBridge.error.description=NSViewBridgeErrorCanceled}
error   11:23:16.172961+0100    spindump    Calendar [51860]: slow hid response (2.5): no existing spin rate event when expected


Please quit Calendar and navigate in the Finder to the folder ~/Library/Containers, which you can do by copying and pasting the path into the Go > Go to Folder... dialog box. Inside that folder are several subfolders with names beginning in "Calendar". Some of them may seem to have the same name, but that's not really true. Move all those folders to the Desktop, then launch Calendar. At first you'll have no calendars, but they should resynchronize with the cloud in a minute or two. Any change?

If there's no improvement, quit Calendar again and put back the folders you moved, overwriting the ones that will have been created in their place. Now go to the folder ~/Library/Group Containers and move the subfolder named group.com.apple.calendar to the Desktop. Test again.

Thanks for your suggestions. There was no improvement after the 1st one, and as to the 2nd one, this is where I lost all my calendars and they never re-synchronized; I only had the "On my Mac" calendar and the freeze behaviour was still there even for events in this local calendar.

Please reverse the steps you took. You should now be back where you started. Now quit Calendar, launch the Console application, and select "Errors and Faults" from the toolbar at the top of the window. Then click "Start", launch Calendar, and do whatever reproduces the problem with Calendar. Click "Pause" in the Console window. You'll have a huge number of log messages, far too many to post here. Try to be selective and post only about 50 or less that seem relevant. I can't be much more specific. Please post the text in a code block in your original question, not a screenshot.

It's not as clear as I hoped, but there may be at least one corrupt event in the Calendar database. If I understand correctly, you were able to reproduce the problem with your iCloud and Google calendars absent. Please confirm that by disabling them and testing. If you can still reproduce the problem in that state, try deleting the last "On My Mac" event that was created before the problem started.
